# Customise customer portal login page

Tags: apex, visualforce, customer-portal

Is it possible to customise the login page for my customer portal?
All I really needed to edit is the CSS for the page.

If thats not possible is there a way I can include JS into the page so I can manipulate the design via JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a Force.com Site and associating it with your portal.  Then you can use VF pages for you portal.  You can have a fully customized login page using any CSS or js you want.  I would investigate using Sites

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_customer_portal_setup.htm

Comment: I have read through the content in the URL provided, but all information is related to Communities, not Customer Portal. There is no option in my Customer Portal settings page to change the login page, simply the cotent that appears on top of the login box (via Documents)

Comment: The option won't be in your customer portal settings page, it will be in the Site settings.  There you can specify the URl of your login page.

Comment: Hmm it seems that creating a new site opens up a whole new can of worms... Do I need to recreate the whole portal here or just the login page? How can I create a login page which will interface with the customer portal?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own login page and do what do you want on your custom login page.

Some links helps you to make things easy

http://appirio.com/category/tech-blog/2013/10/create-custom-salesforce-communities-login-landing-page/

http://cloudcatamaran.com/2013/11/customer-community-customization-part-1/

Thanks

Comment: Please read my response to sfdc_ninja